# Feature projection available through the REST API?

Tags: weaviate

The documentation suggests [in at least one place](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest/objects) that the REST API should be able to return the projected vector information:

> Allowed values [for the `include` parameter] include: `classification`, `vector`, `featureProjection` and other module-specific additional properties.

However, if I call the API with `include=featureProjection`, I get a 400 response that says, "unrecognized property 'featureProjection' in ?include list". (I've also tried `_featureProjection` and `feature-projection`, just in case.)

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the request and response in Postman:

[image: screenshot of Postman showing an example request and the error response]

Calling the GraphQL Get endpoint does return this information [as advertised](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/additional-properties#feature-projection), so I don't think that the issue is a module that I need to enable, but maybe so?

Comment: Could you add an example of the complete URL you are calling? It should be something of the type: `https://example.com/v1/objects?include=featureProjection`  - is that what you have tried?

Comment: Added screenshot. The full URL in this case is `http://localhost:7777/v1/objects?include=featureProjection&class=Session`

Comment: Looks like a bug in the REST API then... I cannot see anything incorrect in your call